# How to show only one language when the page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, translate

i have used a script from jQueryscript.net for translating, I'm using it on prebuilt theme so i think that the theme's css is preventing my code to applay first,
in the console i can't see the inline style when the page load, but when i switch the language it dose and it switch perfectly
**HTML**:

```
<head>
    <style>
        li[lang="en"] {display: none}
        li[lang="ar"] {display: none}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navigation-navbar collapsed">
    <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
        <li lang="en"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
        <li lang="ar"><a href="#hero">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
    <script src="jquery-simple-multi-lang.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function() {

      $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $("li[lang]").languageSwitcher( $(this).attr("id") );
      });

    });

    </script>
</body>
```

**jquery-simple-multi-lang.js:**

```
(function($){
  $.fn.languageSwitcher = function(lang){
    $.each(this, (index, value) => {
        if (lang == $(value).attr("lang")) {
          $(value).css("display", "inline");
        } else {
          $(value).css("display", "none");
        }
      });      
    return this;
  }
}(jQuery));
```

**in the console when the page load, it shows both languages:**

```
    <div class="navigation-navbar collapsed">
      <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
        <li lang="en" class="active"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
        <li lang="ar" class="active"><a href="#hero">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**in the console when i use the switcher it applay style perfectly and shows the chosen language:**

```
 <div class="navigation-navbar collapsed">
   <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
     <li lang="en" class="active" style="display: inline;"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
     <li lang="ar" class="active" style="display: none;"><a href="#hero">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: That is a weird design decision. Google around for `i18n`

Comment: thanks, that what I have searched for, but this was the easiest one. at first, I have tried to do it with vue.js but I faced a lot of problems and errors because the theme is prebuilt

Comment: Run `languageSwitcher()` once at startup?

Comment: unfortunately, i have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because there is no click to any input radio so any `li` will not visible.

To display `en` onload without javascript modification, change the CSS and add `checked` to the selected radio

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    $("li[lang]").languageSwitcher($(this).attr("id"));
  })

});

(function($) {
  $.fn.languageSwitcher = function(lang) {
    $.each(this, (index, value) => {
      if (lang == $(value).attr("lang")) {
        $(value).css("display", "inline");
      } else {
        $(value).css("display", "none");
      }
    });
    return this;
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```css
/* 
Set all li element to hidden
but not li that has [lang="en"]
*/
li[lang]:not(li[lang="en"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-navbar collapsed">
  <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
    <li lang="en"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
    <li lang="ar"><a href="#hero">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
    <li lang="jp"><a href="#hero">ホームホームة</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- add checked to the "en" -->
  en: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="en" checked>
  ar: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="ar">
  jp: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="jp">
</div>
```

to use jQuery to click first radio

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    $("li[lang]").languageSwitcher($(this).attr("id"));
  })

  $("input[type=radio]")[0].click(); // add this line
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.languageSwitcher = function(lang) {
    $.each(this, (index, value) => {
      if (lang == $(value).attr("lang")) {
        $(value).css("display", "inline");
      } else {
        $(value).css("display", "none");
      }
    });
    return this;
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```css
li[lang] {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navigation-navbar collapsed">
  <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left">
    <li lang="en"><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
    <li lang="ar"><a href="#hero">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
    <li lang="jp"><a href="#hero">ホームホームة</a></li>
  </ul>

  en: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="en" />
  ar: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="ar" />
  jp: <input type="radio" name="lang" id="jp" />
</div>
```